Using C++23 std library in Xcode 15 instead of Apple std library
I've started learning C++23 with C++23 From Beginner to Pro by Ivor Horton and Peter Van Weert.
I'm using Xcode 15.2 so I created new Console application for Mac OS and set compiler to -std=c++2b which enables C++23.
But, unfortunately, when I started coding, I've noticed that std library works different than described in the book.
For example, I can't compile this example:
// Ex2_01.cpp - Writing values of variables to the screen
import std;
int main()
{
  int apple_count {15};                            // Number of apples
  int orange_count {5};                            // Number of oranges
  int total_fruit {apple_count + orange_count};    // Total number of fruit
  std::println("The value of apple_count is {}", apple_count);
  std::println("The value of orange_count is {}", orange_count);
  std::println("The value of total_fruit is {}", total_fruit);
}

// Error: No member 'println' in namespace 'std', did you mean printf?
I've found that it is because Apple replaced println with print:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/4088 (this thread is about swift but I guess they did the same in C++ std library).
I guess many same issues ahead if I won't change apple std library to original one.
Can you please tell me how that library can be replaced in Xcode 15?
Thank you so much. I'm new to Xcode and C++.

Apple replaced println with print: this is not true, don't mix swift and C++. AppleClang doesn't fully support C++23 formatting print library. Install llvm clang.

Thank you, I have already done it using brew. But, unfortunately, I got some troubles compiling my code with it (I created "3rd party build" project but dunno what are correct arguments for it in Xcode for running the build. When I compile, I get "no input files error" - this means that Xcode doesn't call the compiler with right arguments. Can you please help with documentation on it?
